# C++ / Arduino IDE. Publish float to MQTT - is conversion to string -> array necessary?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to publish a float to an MQTT channel in C++, within the Arduino IDE.

The following code does appear to work, but it seems to be a bit long-winded. I cobbled it together from stuff I found online. Is all this really necessary (the conversion to an array via a string), or is there a better way?

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SparkFunBME280.h>

BME280 atmosSensor;

String tStr;
String pStr;
String hStr;
char tArr[4];
char pArr[4];
char hArr[4];

void setup() {
    Setup wifi, mqtt, etc.
}


void loop() {
  float tempReading = atmosSensor.readTempC();
  float pressureReading = atmosSensor.readFloatPressure();
  float humidityReading = atmosSensor.readFloatHumidity();
  tStr = String(tempReading);
  pStr = String(pressureReading);
  hStr = String(humidityReading);
  tStr.toCharArray(tArr, tStr.length()+1);
  pStr.toCharArray(pArr, pStr.length()+1); 
  hStr.toCharArray(hArr, hStr.length()+1); 
  client.publish("atmos1/temperature", tArr);
  client.publish("atmos1/pressure", pArr);
  client.publish("atmos1/humidity", hArr);
}
```

N.B. I have pruned this code down considerably, to just the relevant bit. I'm really just asking whether the conversion to a String, and then to an array etc, is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dtostrf` to do the conversion in fewer steps.

```
char* dtostrf(double __val, signed char __width, unsigned char __prec, char * __s )
```

It would look something like this:

```
 void loop()    
 {
    float humidityReading = atmosSensor.readFloatHumidity();
    constexpr size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 7; //1 char for the sign, 1 char for the decimal dot, 4 chars for the value & 1 char for null termination
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
    dtostrf(humidityReading, BUFFER_SIZE - 1 /*width, including the decimal dot and minus sign*/, 2 /*precision*/, buffer);
    client.publish("atmos1/humidity", buffer, BUFFER_SIZE); //notice we're using the overload where you specify the length of the buffer, as we know it and it saves a call to strlen
 }
```

A cursory glance at the MQTT source code shows that the data is stored in an internal buffer after a call to `publish()`, so you should be safe in reusing the same buffer for multiple calls to `publish()`. But be sure to check more thoroughly than I did ;)